# How can I make a file "permanent" in a Linux live version?

Tags: linux, live

I am working with a live Linux version. If I create a user and that user creates a file, how can I make that file visible for that user after I have restarted the system? (Normally it would be erased)

Comment: Use a USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the file in the device's hard drive, if you are using a CD/DVD.

In case you are using a flash drive, you can save the file in the root `/` folder.

**Note**: Be careful with name given in root folder, try to avoid things like *boot* or other names found in that folder. They are used to start the live system and boot manager usually recognize them based only in file names